# Gradle unable to rebuild in android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle

So i am still new to android studio and after finishing a test project,i kept getting errors about the gradle build and i dont understand what to do

```
startup failed:
build file 'C:\Users\*******\AndroidStudioProjects\Provac\build.gradle': 1: unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   ^

1 error
```

The actual build.gradle file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"/>
```

Comment: This is not the gradle file, it's a resource file in drawable folder, just copy the error you get in the build and paste here. Thanks

Comment: No this the actual file not an xml i think it got corrupt

Comment: This is not and android studio gradle file. Paste the error you are getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `build.gradle` file has been overwritten by an unrelated XML file, either due to human error or a bug in some piece of software.

If you have a backup or an earlier version of your code from version control, you should restore from it.  Otherwise, you'll need to recreate your `build.gradle` file manually.  The `build.gradle` file created by the Android Studio new project wizard is probably a good start, if you have to do that.